# `git clone project2` in gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like Gitlab CI to fetch source code of another project. Is there a better way than adding a read-only deploy key and setting it up in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use [GIT SUBMODULES](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) within your project A to refer to project B and then add

`GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive`

to the gitlab-ci.yml file in project A.

This also enables you to specifically include a specific branch or commit from your subproject.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.html