# GitLab: How can I use code from another repository in pipeline job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab project looking like this:
[image]

During the build of both first-api and second-api I will need to execute the database-migration to be able to run integration tests with a database started as a service.

Since the repository is public I tried to clone database-migration, build and then execute. Unfortionatly it fails on the clone step. This is from my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
init_db:
  stage: build
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab.com/groupname/database-migration.git
    - cd database-migration
    - mvn exec:java
```

I get this error:

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/groupname/database-migration.git
Cloning into 'database-migration'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Is this the correct approach or is there a better solution? If this is the correct approach; how do I make it work?

**Edit, trying submodules**

After input that I should use submodules I changed my approach. 
I have added a file `.gitmodules` to first-api looking like this:

```
[submodule "database-migration"]
  path = database-migration
  url = ../database-migration.git
```

In `.gitlab-ci.yml` I have the following:

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

init_db:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls
    - cd database-migration
    - mvn exec:java
```

The job fails because the folder "database-migration" does not exist.

If you want to look at the repository it can be  found [here](https://gitlab.com/quizemon). I am trying to use submodules in "game-rest-api".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`git clone project2\` in gitlab-ci.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444616/git-clone-project2-in-gitlab-ci-yml)

Comment: I know this is a little late, but why have three repos instead of one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make database-migration as submodule of first-api.
See https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.html

Do not forget to add

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

to .gitlab-ci.yml

i.e.

1. Create submodule

`git clone git@gitlab.com:groupname/first-api.git
cd first-api.git
git submodule add git@gitlab.com:groupname/database-migration.git`

2. Edit .gitmodules

`nano gitmodules`

Replace `git@gitlab.com:groupname/database-migration.git` with  `../../groupname/database-migration.git`

4. Add

`variables:
      GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive`

to .gitlab-ci.yml

4. Commit and push

`git commit -am "Add submodule"
 git push`

Comment: Can someone describe a bit more in detail how to define a submodule? I have created .gitsubmodules and set path to ../database-migration.git. In the log I get ```Updating/initializing submodules recursively...``` but no indication that anything has been downloaded. When I run ```ls``` as a script I do not see anything downloaded either.

Comment: @DavidBerg I added some details to my answer. You have to use `git submodule add` command and not just add .gitmodules file